# How to do multiple regression with within-subject independent variables using SPSS?

Tags: multiple-regression, spss, repeated-measures

I have two groups of subjects, both undergoing two experimental conditions. During the experimental conditions, the subjects take questionnaires for evaluation of the mood states, and blood pressure is measured at the same time.

I want to obtain the correlation between blood pressure and the mood ratings, with simultaneous consideration of the effects of group and condition. Thus, I run a multiple regression, with blood pressure being the dependent variable, and mood ratings, condition as well as group being the independent variables.

My question is:
Is this a multiple regression with repeated measures? If so, how can I perform the analysis using SPSS. I have tried analysis -> regression -> linear -> set independent variable and dependent variable, but I'm afraid that the settings do not consider a repeated measures design.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Are the conditions always given in the same order, or are they randomized? Many people (not all) reserve the term "repeated measures" for situations where interventions occur in a particular order, with a measurement taken after each one. It does appear that condition is a within-subjects factor and perhaps the other factors are between-subjects, and a straight regression analysis does not take that into account. I'll defer to the SPSS experts for what to do about that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The conditions are not given randomly. The group 1 take condition A -> condition B, whereas the group 2 take condition B -> condition A. So if the conditions are given randomly , "repeated measures" should not be used? Thank you.

Comment: Not necessarily, depends on some other assumptions being made, and what the software offers. It looks like your design is what is called a crossover. You should be OK if you fit a model with these indep vars: subject ID, condition, and period, where the latter says whether it is the first or second obs on a subject. You need subject ID (as a factor, or classification variable) in the model to explain the variations among subjects, and group is unnecessary. But mood can be added as a covariate. I hope an SPSS expert can step in and help with the details of doing this.